# Go fyne, i can't run a any simple program with fyne

Tags: go, gcc, fyne

I'm trying to get started with Fyne, I installed the gcc64 bit and go, but I don't know why when I run the command it shows me the problem:

[image]

before that, I run the command `go mod init test` and `go mod tidy` and it created the `.mod` and `.sum` files.

why does this problem show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the cc1.exe is not from the gcc installation?
Debugging Windows C compiler installations can be complicated - we have some instructions from scratch on the Fyne docs site https://developer.fyne.io/started/.

Comment: apparently, I had an old 32bit compiler, so I need to delete that and reinstall it.